# Kubernetes Elasticsearch 8.5.3 Statefulset (not ECK) set up username / password

Tags: authentication, elasticsearch, kubernetes, credentials

How to automatically setup the password of the default user `elastic` and add other username/password for Elasticsearch 8.5.3 running on kubernetes cluster with manifests? I am not using ECK. Setting environment variable `ELASTIC_PASSWORD` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [document](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/setup-passwords.html):

> The `elasticsearch-setup-passwords` tool is deprecated and will be
> removed in a future release.

You can manually reset the password for the built-in users (including the elastic user), use the `elasticsearch-reset-password tool`, the Elasticsearch change password API, or the User Management features in Kibana.
The elasticsearch-setup-passwords command sets the passwords for the built-in users.

```
bin/elasticsearch-setup-passwords auto|interactive
[-b, --batch] [-h, --help] [-E <KeyValuePair>]
[-s, --silent] [-u, --url "<URL>"] [-v, --verbose]
```

When you install Elasticsearch, if the elastic user does not already have a password, it uses a default bootstrap password. The bootstrap password is a transient password that enables you to run the tools that set all the built-in user passwords.

By default, the bootstrap password is derived from a randomized keystore.seed setting, which is added to the keystore during installation. You do not need to know or change this bootstrap password. If you have defined a bootstrap.password setting in the keystore, however, that value is used instead.

Also,refer to this [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/built-in-users.html) for more information